# Listening MongoDb change streams with Nifi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I need to sync MongoDb to another database. This task looks classic for Nifi, however [Nifi Documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html) doesn't mention any processor designed to listen for changes in MongoDb. I have found an [old blog post](https://www.compose.com/articles/mongo-to-mongo-data-moves-with-nifi/) describing an interesting solution, but i wonder if there are other approaches, using MongoDb change streams or an alternative way to work with oplog.

Comment: NiFi is not developing DB CDC processors. You could make your own custom procesor, or use a series of existing processors to process the oplog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two variants:

1. Select one column in your source table as increment key, f.e. timestamp, or int identy column. Use FetchDatabaseTable or QueryDatabasetable, define property **Max value column**. Processors will save maximum value and read data between prev_max_value and current_max_value
2. Read all data, check changes, update destinations.